# Table View Header with Landscape iPhone X support

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, ios11, iphone-x

Well, I am trying to make the headers of UITableView compatible with iPhone X Landscape where I want background colors of Header should expand to edge.
I have seen the WWDC video to do that where they said to apply color on backgroundView but in my case it's always nil.

Here is my code and also [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr52tiejdqyi64g/HeaderViewTest.zip?dl=0) to demo of it.

```
extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource{
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String.init(describing: HVTableViewCell.self)) as! HVTableViewCell
    return cell
}
}
extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60.0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: String.init(describing: HVTableViewHeaderFooterView.self)) as? HVTableViewHeaderFooterView{
        if let backgroundView = headerView.backgroundView{
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }else{
            print("Failed")
        }
        return headerView
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tblReference: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tblReference.register(UINib.init(nibName: String.init(describing: HVTableViewCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String.init(describing: HVTableViewCell.self))
    self.tblReference.register(UINib.init(nibName: String.init(describing: HVTableViewHeaderFooterView.self), bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: String.init(describing: HVTableViewHeaderFooterView.self))

    self.tblReference.delegate = self
    self.tblReference.dataSource = self

    self.tblReference.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Here is the screenshot of the issue.
[image: Yellow Header Should stretch to edges.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do it.

We can set the background color of Layer of HeaderView.

```
// HeaderView Class
self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Here is [the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cq43m36dbfkuibd/HeaderViewTest_Working.zip?dl=0) of working code.

Hope it helps to others as well.